# jQuery checking for visibility doesnt work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a web application for managing orders and finance for a restaurant. For that in my application i need more screens to work with. I've got this small function to switch between those visibility's:

```
function switchTab(toActivate, toDeactivate) {
    var $toActivate = $(toActivate);
    var $toDeactivate = $(toDeactivate);

    if ($toDeactivate.is(":visible")) {
        $toDeactivate.css("visibility", "hidden");
        $toActivate.css("visibility", "visible");
    }
}
```

I have also created a function for deleting one of the existing orders, this same function is to delete a order when your one the screen when creating one.

```
function delete_order() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this order?")) {
        if ($("#new-order").is(":visible")) {
            switchTab(orderListScreen, newOrderScreen);
            switchTab(orderInformationScreen, availableProductsScreen);

            alert("Only this is getting called");
        } else if ($("#list").is(":visible")) {
            $(".selectedRow").remove();

            alert("Why doesnt this get called?");
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

Whenever i'm creating a order, and im deleting it then by the delete button (where the `delete_order()` function is getting called) its working fine, because its calling the right part of the code ( `if (newOrderScreen.is(":visible"))` ).

But whenever i'm trying to delete an existing order, it doesnt work. It just calls the same upper part of the code again.

The code for creating a new order (actually just bringing up the screen) is this:

```
function new_order() {
    switchTab(newOrderScreen, orderListScreen);
    switchTab(availableProductsScreen, orderInformationScreen);
}
```

- Note: The `.selectedRow` class is given when selecting a row.
- Note: The `#list` screen is standard displayed, the `#new-order` screen is only displayed when clicking the button for it.

The CSS for the 2 screens that are switching is:

```
#new-order {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#list {
    display: block;
}
```

**Question**

How does it come that it doesnt take the right part of the `if` statement? And why does it work in the first place when bringing up the screen for a new order?

Comment: Hard to answer without a jsfiddle to fiddle around ;) Does `$("#list").is(":visible")` returns false? Perhaps it's because it's entering your first `if` statement? Note that you have used and `else if`, meaning only one or the other will be entered, not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the JQuery API docs:

`Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.`

This information is available [here](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

That's why your if statement doesn't work the way you think it should.

Check if new-Order is set to visibility:hidden or not in your first if statement, instead of checking whether or not it is visible.

Just had a chat with the JavaScript boys as well, you can use jQuery .hide() to set it as not :visible before running your if statement, as well.

Comment: Alright, can you give me an example for that? And do i still need to use the function i wrote?

Comment: That was before you editid your post, going to try some stuff now.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I posted a pretty dumb idea before thinking of checking for vis hidden instead :)

Comment: I'm using this line now: `if (newOrderScreen.is(":hidden")) {` and its still not working. its only calling the other one.

Comment: Hmm. Are you setting it as hidden before running your if statement, even when going to newOrderScreen?

Comment: You mean in my CSS? then yes

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting my head around the way your code works. If you want to remove a row, using your current if statement, you'd need to set new-Order to use `display:none;` or use .hide() _prior_ to running the if statement. Otherwise, the logic in your if statement needs to change.